# Is Prism.Core supported in .NET MAUI?

Tags: prism, maui

I am converting my Xamarin Forms Application to .NET MAUI.I need to inherit Prism.MVVM.BindableBase class in my solution

Is Prism.Core(8.1.97) package supported in .NET MAUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prism is working on .NET MAUI support, it's currently in preview. Find a couple of links below to get you started:

- NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Maui
- Docs: https://prismlibrary.com/docs/maui/index.html
- Repo: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism.Maui